# Continuity of functions on a union

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If we have a function, that's defined on a union, say $f:[0,1]\cup(2,3] \longrightarrow [0,2]$
and we have that $f(x)=x$ when $x\in[0,1]$ and  $f(x)=x-1$ when $x\in(2,3]$
then can $f$ be continuous? I think that it is since although there's a gap, it isn't defined there, so it is continuous everywhere on its domain but I can't rigorously show this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Yes: the function is continuous, since it is continous at every point of its domain.

Comment: How can we show this rigorously?

Comment: What I wronte in my comment is rigorous enough. For all $x \in [0,1]$, for all neighbourhoods of $x$, $f$ equals a continuous function, hence $f$ is continuous at $x$. The same for all $x \in (2,3]$.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is continuous. Is $A,B\subset\mathbb R$ are such that, for some $\varepsilon>0$,$$(\forall a\in A)(\forall b\in B):|a-b|\geqslant\varepsilon$$and if $f\colon A\cup B\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is such that $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are continuous, then $f$ is continuous. This is so because if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of elements of $A\cup B$ wich converges to $x\in A\cup B$, then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. If, for instance, $x\in A$, then, because of the gap between $A$ and $B$, $x_n\in A$ if $n\gg1$. Therefore, since $f|A$ is continuous, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$. If $x\in B$, the argument is the same.